# How to check whether a date is in the next week, python

Tags: python, date, datetime

Basically, I'm trying to check whether a date, e.g. 2021-07-08, is in the next week, or the week after that, or neither.

```
#I can call the start and end dates of the current week

start = tday - timedelta(days=tday.weekday())
end = start + timedelta(days=6)
print("Today: " + str(tday))
print("Start: " + str(start))
print("End: " + str(end))

# and I can get the current week number. 

curr_week = datetime.date.today().strftime("%V")
print(curr_week)
```

Is there a better way than getting a list of dates in curr_week + 1 and then checking whether date is in in that list?
Thanks so much

Comment: I rolled back the edit which removed your code. You really don't want to post a question like this without a demonstration of where you are with your own coding effort.

Comment: A bit "hacky", but `int(datetime(2021, 8, 17).strftime("%V")) - int(datetime.now().strftime("%V")) == 1` checks if `2021-08-17` is next week from today.

Comment: Your `start` ends up on the correct day but at some random time during that day. I would find the start of that day and simply add a `timedelta(days=7)` to that successively to find the start of the following week, and the following after that.

Comment: instead of timedelta, have a look at [isocalendar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isocalendar) - you can easily get the week number of any date from that method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### GENERAL ANSWER

It is best to stick to datetime and timedelta, since this handles all edge cases like year changes, years with 53 weeks etc.

So find the number of the next week, and compare the weeknumber of the week you want to check against that.

```
import datetime

# Date to check in date format:
check_date = datetime.datetime.strptime("2021-09-08", "%Y-%d-%m").date()

# Current week number:
curr_week = datetime.date.today().strftime("%V")
# number of next week
next_week = (datetime.date.today()+datetime.timedelta(weeks=1)).strftime("%V")
# number of the week after that
week_after_next_week = (datetime.date.today()+datetime.timedelta(weeks=2)).strftime("%V")


# Compare week numbers of next weeks to the week number of the date to check:
if next_week == check_date.strftime("%V"):
    # Date is within next week, put code here
    pass
elif week_after_next_week == check_date.strftime("%V"):
    # Date is the week after next week, put code here
    pass
```

### OLD ANSWER

This messes up around year changes, and modulo doesn't fix it because there are years with 53 weeks.

You can compare the week numbers by converting them to integers. You don't need to create a list of all dates within the next week.

```
import datetime

# Date to check in date format:
check_date = datetime.datetime.strptime("2021-07-08", "%Y-%d-%m").date()

# Current week number, make it modulo so that the last week is week 0:
curr_week = int(datetime.date.today().strftime("%V"))

# Compare week numbers:
if curr_week == (int(check_date.strftime("%V"))-1):
    # Date is within next week, put code here
    pass
elif curr_week == (int(check_date.strftime("%V"))-2):
    # Date is the week after next week, put code here
    pass
```

Comment: makes much more sense, thanks mate. Why -1 and -2? Why does it work like that?

Comment: If a date is in the next week, its week number will be 1 higher than the current week number, and if it is in the week after its number will be 2 higher. Now that I think of it, this will cause issues around the end of the year where the week numbers reset, let me make an edit.

Comment: what did you change?

Comment: I realized it became more difficult by doing it the simple way, so added a more general answer just now. This works a bit different, but should contain the edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast the date you want to check in datetime, and then compare the week numbers.

```
# date you want to check
date = datetime.datetime.strptime("2021-07-08","%Y-%m-%d")

# current date
tday = datetime.date.today()

# compare the weeks
print(date.strftime("%V"))
print(tday.strftime("%V"))

27
32
```

Answer (score 1):

[**see Alfred's answer**]

You can get the week number directly as an integer integer from the `IsoCalendarDate` representation of each date.

```
from datetime import datetime
date_format = '%Y-%m-%d'
t_now = datetime.strptime('2021-08-11', date_format)
target_date = datetime.strptime('2021-08-18', date_format)
```

Comment: This doesn't handle year-boundaries well, so Alfred's answer works best. I should've remembered to avoid manually implementing date-based arithmetic keeping in mind Tom Scott's video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY

Answer (score 0):

Just using datetime comparing:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


def in_next_week(date):
    """ -1: before; 0: in; 1: after next week;"""
    today = datetime.today()
    this_monday = today.date() - timedelta(today.weekday())
    start = this_monday + timedelta(weeks=1)
    end = this_monday + timedelta(weeks=2)
    return -1 if date < start else 0 if date < end else 1
```

Test cases:

```py
for i in range(14):
    dt = datetime.today().date() + timedelta(days=i)
    print(dt, in_next_week(dt))
```